After installing latest version of android studio, all backward arrow and navigation menu icon change into word. I try a lot but fail
this is error backward arrow change into word.
I face this problem when i install latest version of android studio. All icon not showing but falcon icon working.

"All icon not showing" So you want all icons? or just want to display backward arrow?
